# "An error occured! Please check your internet connection"

Tags: 14.04

yesterday I managed to download **Osu!**, It worked correctly but I made a mistake with wine and **Osu!** didn't start even if i repaired Wine. So I decided to re install it and It shows :

[image]

(I didn't get this problem yesterday)

Considering the game worked perfectly yesterday, I don't think that the updater has a problem.
Can you help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Try PlayOnLinux to install the game. If this does not help, you need to remove every data remainders from your virtual wine drive:

1.Copy **everything that you need** (do not copy everything, this will result reappearing the problem) from your virtual wine drive (it's default location is /home/[user]/.wine/drive_c)

2.Go to *Wine->winetricks*, check the box *Select the default prefix* and click OK, after that check **Delete ALL DATA AND APPLICATIONS INSIDE THIS WINEPREFIX** and click OK and confirm that.

3.Then install Osu!. This should work.

Note: Use this solution as the last choice, because this will recreate your .wine folder and all program files inside .wine are deleted. So you need to Backup.